# Swift: consecutive CABasicAnimations that repeat

Tags: ios, swift, animation, timing, caanimation

Goal:

- First animation runs for a duration of 1.0
- At 1.0, the second animation runs (while the first animation autoreverses back to its starting point)
- At 2.0, the first animation is back at its starting point, the second animation has completed, and the first animation repeats
- At 3.0, the second animation runs as the first animation concludes its second run

My code:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 1.5
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        image1.layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)

        let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        animation2.fromValue = 1.0
        animation2.toValue = 2.0
        animation2.duration = 1.0
        animation2.fillMode = .forwards

        let animation2b = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        animation2b.fromValue = 1.0
        animation2b.toValue = 0.0
        animation2b.duration = 1.0
        animation2b.fillMode = .forwards

        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.animations = [animation2, animation2b]
        animationGroup.duration = 2.0
        animationGroup.beginTime = 1.0
        animationGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        image2.layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "scaleAndFade")
```

The goal is to start the 2nd animation 1.0 after the 1st animation. And since the animation group has a duration of 2.0 while the animations within it have a duration of only 1.0, the animation would start at 1.0, end at 2.0, and then not repeat again until 3.0

The two animations sometimes match up, but not on every build. Is there a more surefire way of starting the second animation to begin exactly at the end of the initial animation's first completed animation? So that they'll be in sync from that point on. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the first animation autoreverse and repeat count. Just describe the whole thing as individual animations and let the group do the repeating.

Comment: @matt what if the first animation (with autoreverse which I could break into 2 animations) is added to the layer of one imageview, and the second group of animations (the scale and fade) are on a second different imageview - would you still recommend something similar? Each group would be attached to a different view... would it be better just to use UIView.animate and its completion: block?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I see, you can’t do a group on two different layers! Will have to link via completion handlers. Can do that with views or layers. Use recursion to get the repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @matt's answer and always appreciate their input but since I was trying to use CAAnimation (specifically I wanted to use CAKeyframeAnimation), I ended up nesting two CATransactions using `CATransaction.begin()` and `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock` to start one animation exactly at the end of the other and then to recursively call the function repeatedly.

[CATransaction documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransaction)

Answer (score 1):

I’m a little unclear on what we’re trying to achieve, but my sense is that the idea is that we have two views with repeating animations that need to be coordinated. To demonstrate an example of how this might be done, I chose to make both animations be a scale-up followed by a scale-down:

[image]

The animated gif here comes to an end after a few repetitions, but in actual fact the repetition just goes on forever.

That was simply achieved as follows:

```
func step1() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.v1.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        self.v2.transform = .identity
    }) { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.step2()
        }
    }
}

func step2() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.v1.transform = .identity
        self.v2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }) { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.step1()
        }
    }
}
```

The point is that the stages of the animation can never get out of sync between the two views, because each stage involves *both* views and *follows* the previous stage. So I’m pretty sure you can adapt that approach to fit your animation.

Comment: Thanks for always answering and pushing me to think about my questions. I often use a similar code structure to these 2 functions you've shown here. See my answer for what I ended up doing specific to CAAnimations.

Comment: Sounds excellent. I recently had reason to use CATransaction nesting myself and was amazed at how it solved all the problems I was having. (In particular, I wanted to fire off a large but unknown number of animations in a for-loop, and then run a completion block when they had _all_ finished.) Sometimes reaching down to this level is the best way.